# Open Set Examples in Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

I cannot understand why $\mathbb {R\setminus Q}$ is a $G_{\delta}$ set in $(-\infty,0]$

I can’t imagine any open set in real numbers except intervals. Which open sets’ intersection is Irrational numbers? $(\le 0)$

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Take the open sets $(-\infty,0]\setminus\{r\} $.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is r?

Comment: $r$ ranges over the (negative) rationals.

Comment: I am sorry if I have misunderstood, $(-\infty,0] \setminus \{r\}$ is an interval without rationals? Is it still open? Does it contain all neighborhoods (balls) of every elements of this set? How??

Comment: No, it's a union of two intervals: $ (-\infty, r) $ and $(r, 0]$ which are open in $(-\infty, 0]$. Then take the intersection of all these with $r\in\Bbb Q$.

Comment: I am so sorry. I have just understood correctly. Thanks a lot. Can I do sane thing for positive rationals?

Comment: Sure. The point is that the rationals are *countable*.

Answer (score 2):

With regards to your first question, rationals are clearly $F_\sigma$ (singletons are closed, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable), and it is straightforward to show from DeMorgan's laws that the complement of an $F_\sigma$ set is $G_\delta$.

EDIT: To elaborate, let $A$ be an arbitrary $F_\sigma$ set, and write it as $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$, where each $A_n$ is closed. Take the complement and apply DeMorgan's laws.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I could see it but I wonder type of these open sets..